# Breakdown of Snell

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

I have reason to believe the following:

If we are using an accurately formed thin prism, with an apical angle of   let's say 2 degrees, and direct a monochromatic source beam thru a slit onto the prism toward a location a fraction of a millimeter from the apex, Snell's V1/V2 may require a modification. The fewer atomic layers involved, the greater the modification.

I can't find anything to support this, however.

Normally this would go unnoticed since there is no reason to locate the
incident beam very close to the apex -- one uses a thicker part of the prism.  And, of course, the usual lab prisms don't have such small apical   angles.

Has anyone seen a reference to this?

Comment: Snell's law seems to work correctly when applied to thin films made from materials thicknesses of 1/4 and 1/2 wavelength of high and low index materials.  For red light that would be 150 to 300 nm thick.  Why do you believe if fails for a thin prism?  One must also take into account diffraction effects, but that doesn't  invalidate Snell's law.

Comment: *"They have their own methods."* Do you mean the lens maker's formula? It's based on Snell's Law, Euclidian geometry and an assumption that the lens is thin-compared to its transverse extent. Those lenses are no where near thin enough to worry about surface effects.

Comment: When the object becomes very thin compared to the wavelength, all bets are off. Photons may simply not interact with the material as each atom has a finite cross section (probability of interaction) - So REALLY thin materials don't quite appear to obey Snells' law. But once the material is thick enough that all incident photons interact, Snells' law works just fine. Quarter wavelength or greater is no problem. Can you give a reference for your assertion that Snell's law is not obeyed?

Comment: "Any comments?" isn't a good question for this site... it invites only comments, not answers, as you see here.